# adding folders that are empty to disallowed array

Tags: php, arrays, filesystems, directory

I am using an array which allows me to prevent particular subfolders from being included in a script that generates an audio playlist.  It looks like this:

```
$disallowed=array('..', '.', 'simon', 'steve');
```

I would like to find a way of disallowing any folders which are empty, or, perhaps, better still, disallowing folders that do not have any MP3s in them (in case the script interprets folders as not empty if they contain system files which are automatically generated).

I included the full script below so that you can see how the disallowed array fits in.

Would someone be able to help with this?

Thanks,

Nick

```
<?php

/*
* =====================
* FUNctions
* =====================
*/

/*
* array subvalue sort -- from: http://www.firsttube.com/read/sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array-with-php/
*
* this function lets me sort the multidimensional array containing song/artist information by the file modified time, a subvalue
*/
function subval_sort($a,$subkey) {
    foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
        $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
    }
    arsort($b); //change this to 'asort' for ascending
    foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
        $c[] = $a[$key];
    }
    return $c;
}

/*
* function written to clean up my messy code (too many slashes ... display '/' as '&raquo' (>>) for user friendliness )
*/
function clean($dirty, $type='general', $debug=false){

    //debug
    if($debug==true)
        echo'<br />value before clean: '.$dirty.' (first character: '.substr($dirty, 0, 1).')';

    /*
    * General cleaning -- remove '/' at front and end
    */
    if(substr($dirty, 0, 1)=='/'){
        //echo'<br />found leading /';
        $dirty=substr($dirty, 1, strlen($dirty)-1);
    }

    if(substr($dirty, -1)=='/')
        $dirty=substr($dirty, 0, strlen($dirty)-1);


    //prepare the subfolder display information by type
    if($type=='link')
        $dirty=str_replace(array('//','&raquo;'), array('/', '/'), $dirty); 

    else if($type=='display')
        $dirty=str_replace(array('///','//','/'), array('&raquo;','&raquo;', '&raquo;'), $dirty);   

    else
        $dirty=str_replace('&raquo;', '/', $dirty);


    if($debug==true)echo' | after clean: '.$dirty;

    //return
    return $dirty;
}

function makelink($linkme, $debug=false){
    $link=str_replace('&raquo;', '/', $linkme);
    $link=str_replace('//', '/', $link);
    return $link;

}

function recursiveGetSongs($directory, $fileinfo, $useID3, $getID3, $parent=null, $debug, $filtered=null){

    /*
    * configure function here:
    *
    * _usage_
    *   > the disallowed array should include any folders or files you explicitely don't want displayed
    *   > the allowedfiletypes array should include any file extentions you want to play
    */
    $disallowed=array('..', '.', 'simon', 'steve');
    $allowedfiletypes=array('mp3');

    if($filtered!=null){
        $disallowed=array_merge((array)$filtered, (array)$disallowed);
    }

    //simple error fix
    if($directory=='./')
        $directory='.';

    //debug
    if ($debug==true)echo'Dir to open: '.$directory;

    //open directory
    $dir = opendir($directory); 

    while ($read = readdir($dir)) 
    {

        //if ( !in_array($read, $disallowed) AND ( $filter!=null AND in_array($read, $filter) ) )
        if ( !in_array($read, $disallowed) )
        { 
            if($debug==true)echo $read.'<br />';
            //if is not dir, handle file
            if ( !is_dir($directory.'/'.$read) ){

                if($debug==true)echo '^^ not dir | dir: '.$directory.'<br />';

                if( in_array(substr($read, -3, 3), $allowedfiletypes) ){

                    if($useID3==TRUE){

                    //store id3 info
                    $FullFileName = realpath($directory.'/'.$read);
                    if($debug==TRUE)echo'<br />FFN &raquo; '.$FullFileName;
                    $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($FullFileName);
                    getid3_lib::CopyTagsToComments($ThisFileInfo);
                    $fileinfo[$read]['artist']=$ThisFileInfo['comments_html']['artist'][0];
                    $fileinfo[$read]['title']=$ThisFileInfo['comments_html']['title'][0];
                    $fileinfo[$read]['album']=$ThisFileInfo['comments_html']['album'][0];
                    $fileinfo[$read]['filename']=$ThisFileInfo['filename'];
                    $fileinfo[$read]['modified']=date ("YmdHis", filemtime($directory.'/'.$read));

                    if($debug==true)
                        echo "<br />$read was last modified: " . date ("YmdHis", filemtime($directory.'/'.$read));

                    $fileinfo[$read]['path']=$directory.'/'.$read;
                    if($debug==true)echo'<span style="margin-left: 10px;">path:'.$fileinfo[$read]['path'].' > fn: '.$fileinfo[$read]['filename'].'</span><br /><br />';

                    if($parent!=null)
                        $fileinfo[$read]['from']=str_replace(array('./', '//', '/'), array('', '&raquo;', '&raquo;'), $directory); // was =$parent

                    else
                        $fileinfo[$read]['from']='root'; //testing this

                    if($debug==true)echo'<br />'.$fileinfo[$read]['from'].'<br />';

                    //debug
                    //echo$ThisFileInfo['filename'].'<br />';
                    }
                    else{
                        //store filename
                        $fileinfo[$fileinfo['count']]['path']=$directory.'/'.$read;
                        $fileinfo[$fileinfo['count']]['fn']=$read;
                        if($parent!=null)
                            $fileinfo[$fileinfo['count']]['from']=str_replace(array('./', '//', '/'), array('', '&raquo;', '&raquo;'), $directory);

                        $fileinfo[$fileinfo['count']]['modified']=date ("YmdHis", filemtime($directory.'/'.$read));
                        //$fileinfo[$fileinfo['count']]=date ("YmdHis", filemtime($directory.'/'.$read));
                    }

                    //inc counter
                    $fileinfo['count']=$fileinfo['count']+1; // had ++ and it didn't work
                }
                else
                    ;//do nothing
            }

            //else, must be a folder (as determined above), recurse folder
            else{

                //debug
                if($debug==true)echo '^^ DIR<br />';

                //capture subfolders in case they are needed
                if($parent!='')$fileinfo['folders'].=$parent.'&raquo;'.$read.'|';
                else $fileinfo['folders'].=$read.'|';
                $fileinfo['folderpaths'].=$directory.'/|';

                $fileinfo=recursiveGetSongs($directory.'/'.$read, $fileinfo, $useID3, $getID3, $parent.'/'.$read, $debug, $filtered);

            }

        }

    }
    closedir($dir); 

    return $fileinfo;
}

?>
```

Comment: Sure thing.  I will look at this again.  Last time I looked though there were not answers that worked!  But there may now be one or two more to accept....

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob('somefolder/*.mp3')` to test if there are mp3s in a folder. The function will return an array, so if it's empty the folder does not contain any mp3 files.

Comment: thanks, but I am not sure how I would include this is my script, which I have now included in full in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [glob()](http://hu2.php.net/glob) since it's flexible and a little bit more secure than building up a 'valid array'.

```
foreach (glob($dir . "/*.mp3") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I am not sure how I would include this is my script, which I have now included in full in my original post.

Comment: @Nick Delete the whole directory reading part from `$dir = opendir(`... till the end. The only part you need is the actual ID3 reading piece. Try my snippet on a directory and you'll se what you get. In my snippet `$filename` equals your `$read` variable if i am right.

Comment: thanks.  I tried deleting everything from `$dir = opendir(` through to `closedir($dir);`, putting your snippet in its place, changing `$filename` to `$read`, but then no folders showed up.  My knowledge of php is quite limited (someone else wrote most of the script I posted), so most probably I am showing my ignorance!

Comment: @Nick please at least read `glob()`'s documentation instead of simply copy-paste snippets from everywhere. The example i've wrote is only listing mp3 files from a single directory. Not recursively, not both mp3's and directories but mp3s. In the linked documentation you'll find some examples about recursive directory discovery too.

Comment: @fabrik OK, thanks.  I will look into this, though it may be beyond me (or at least beyond the amount of time I have right now).  I was hoping that there would be a way of simply adding an item/variable to my disallowed array that would exclude empty folders.  Thanks for pointing me in the direction of glob() though.

Comment: @Nick AFAIK no other solution which is cleaner, better for file collecting than glob.